# Why does specifying my shell change the EUID of root?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sudo, ubuntu-14.04

If I specify my shell as /bin/bash in a script, then the EUID of root is 0.  If I don't, and the script runs in my default shell (also /bin/bash), the EUID of root is an empty string!  I'm new to scripting and thought there was no difference as long as bash ran the show.

The code I'm running checks if the program is run by root, and restarts the program as sudo if not.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo euid = $EUID
echo shell = $SHELL

if [ $EUID -ne 0 ]; then
    sudo "$0"
    exit $?
fi
```

When run, I see

```
euid = 1000
shell = /bin/bash
euid = 0
shell = /bin/bash
```

But if I remove the she-bang line, I get

```
euid = 1000
shell = /bin/bash
euid =
shell = /bin/bash
./test.sh: 4: [: -ne: unexpected operator
```

The script runs in the same shell all four times, so why does it act differently when sudo calls it without specifying /bin/bash?

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 if that matters.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure, but a more appropriate check would be to check $USER rather than EUID

Comment: I read that EUID was "the new way" to check who's running the script, but you can't trust everything you read on the internet!

Comment: The problem with EUID is that it is different on every system. "root" will be the same on every system, as well as usernames (well, MOST people use the same usernames) but EUID will be different on every system. (EUID for root will most likely not change, but it is possible)

Comment: Oh!  Well, then I definitely don't want to use EUID, as this script is supposed to run on a few different OSs.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By removing the shebang line, you are calling Ubuntu default shell, which is Dash, not Bash.

Dash does not define `$EUID`, leading to an empty assignment. In fact, `$EUID` is one of many enhancements brought by Bash over the POSIX standard. Instead, Dash is meant to be as small, fast and lightweight as possible, and implements only the minimal set of features required by the standard.

You assert that it runs in the same shell all four times, but in fact it doesn't. The environment variable `$SHELL` does not refer to the shell running the current process; it refers to your account's login shell, defined in `/etc/passwd` or equivalent.

Comment: Oh, ok!  I misunderstood what $SHELL was then.  So how can I see my currently running shell?  Also, can I change the default Ubuntu shell?

Comment: When I googled for both of these, I was told to find the current shell via ps and grep, but I'd like a variable if possible.  I was directed to chsh for the second one, which I'd already found before asking the initial question.

Comment: You can use `ps -p $$ -o fname | tail -n 1` to discover which shell is executing your script (will output `bash`, `dash`, etc.). Use `which $(ps -p $$ -o fname | tail -n 1)` for absolute path to executable (e.g. `/bin/bash`)